# Weight doesn't work in XML code

Tags: xml

When I write xml code below, layout_width and layout_weight don't work,can anyone help me? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lme1n.png)

Comment: what do you mean by "each line"? lines in the text view? Please be more specific

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just added a picture to describe it

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tag names are truncated.. like <L and <T or may be the problem with the editor. Run it on your phone and test it

Comment: yes, your answer can work correctly on my computer, thank you very much, but difference between <L and <LinearLayout should not matter, right?

Comment: Thank you, it does matter. After I changed it, it works right, but why?

Comment: LinearLayout is a class name in android, L isn't. Can you use S instead of System? Nope right?

Comment: Oh~~, that is the problem I don't get: it is a class name, thank you